# How to convert .sdv file to Excel file?

Tags: data-cleaning, data-collection

I want to convert a .sdv file that I have into a excel file. How can I achieve this?

I tried this approach:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Tlz.png)
But I can't find any option in excel to even find this file. Is it possible to do it in Excel or any other platform?